# Get column names when using TPT table to file

Tags: sql, teradata

I am using TPT (Teradata Parallel Transporter) to pull a heavy query into a csv file, But the output is the data without the column names.
is there a way to get the column names when using TPT?

my job file:

```
using character set UTF8 
    define job tpt_table_to_file 
    ( 
        set MaxDecimalDigits = 38; 
        apply to operator ($file_writer) 
        select * from operator ($export) 
        ; 
    );
```

var file:

```
SourceTdpId = <Source>
SourceUserName = <uid>
SourceUserPassword = <pwd>
SelectStmt = 'select a.*, b.* from a join b on a.id=b.id'
TargetFileName = <'desitnation/output.csv'>
TargetFormat = 'delimited'
TargetTextDelimiter = ','
```

Comment: Unless something has changed, I don't think you can directly get headers.  You can either have a file on your OS with your header and then cat the files together, or build your header row in your script, and union all that together with your main query.